# Computing average in randomization inference

Tags: stata

Suppose I have the following simulated data:

```
set obs 10
set seed 125
gen tau = runiform()
```

Assume that 3 out of 10 observations are 'treated', but we do not know which observations are treated. I want to find the average value of the tau variable for all possible combinations, i.e. in 10C3=120 combinations.

For example, suppose observation 1, 5, and 6 are treated. Then average tau for this combination is (tau[1]+tau[5]+tau[6])/3 = 0.57. There are 120 of such combinations that are available, and I would like to compute this average value for all possible combinations.

How can I code this in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear to me what format you want the data on in the end, but here is a solution that calculates the stats you are looking for.

```
clear

tempfile averages
save `averages', emptyok

set obs 10
set seed 125
gen tau = runiform()

* Loop over the possible observartion numbers
forvalues i = 1/10 {
    forvalues j = 1/10 {
        forvalue k = 1/10 {
            
            * Make sure to use combination and not permutation
            if (`i' < `j') & (`j' < `k') {
                
                preserve
                    
                    * keep only 
                    di "`i', `j', `k'"
                    keep if _n == `i' | _n == `j' | _n == `k'
                    
                    * Get mean from these obs in one row
                    collapse (mean) tau
                    * Store which observations used for this row
                    gen obs_combo = "`i', `j', `k'"
                    
                    * Append to dataset
                    append using `averages'
                    save `averages', replace
                
                restore
            }
        }
    }
}

* Load the averages
use `averages', clear
order obs_combo tau
```